# Resharper "The condition (project != null) is false"

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I recently reinstalled resharper 4.5 for vs2008 and I'm getting the "The condition (project != null) is false" exception as it's checking the assemblies.  Prior to uninstalling resharper, it was working fine.

I've tried, uninstalling/reinstalling resharper again.  Uninstalling/re-installing vs2008.  Neither of which worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pat

Answer (score 3):

Try installing a later build of ReSharper from the [Nightly Builds site](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+4.5+Nightly+Builds). I recently installed build 1277, and it's very stable and great.

Also, try deleting the ReSharper cache from the root of your solution (folder starting with `_ReSharper.*`), and if you have any 3<sup>rd</sup> party plugins, such as [Agent Smith](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/), try disabling them (in ReSharper → Plugins).